# Keep iterating through HashSet while items are being added and removed

Tags: c#, .net, list, hashset

How to iterate through a HashSet while adding and removing items? 
Keep in mind that in the real program sometimes nothing will be added to the list, so there is an end to the list and it isn't an endless loop.

For example:

```
static HashSet<int> listThingy = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2 } ;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var item in listThingy)
    {
        listThingy.Add(3);
        listThingy.Remove(item);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Output should be something like this:

```
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
etc..
```

In the program I will be adding random values to the list (sometimes nothing will be added) till all the values have been processed.

Comment: Don't use a HashSet. You seem to need a Queue.

Comment: take a look here if you are not familiar with `Queue` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The elements of a HashSet<T> are not ordered. I.e. new elements are not added at the end and the loop will yield the elements in an unpredictable order. Therefore this loop cannot work.

Answer (score -1):

Closest to what you describing is:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> listThingy = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    listThingy.Add(1, null);
    listThingy.Add(2, null);
    foreach (var item in listThingy)
    {
        object val = null;
        listThingy.TryAdd(3, null);
        listThingy.TryRemove(2, val);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't provide the stated functionality.  The added object can end up in a bucket that the dictionary's iterator has already passed over, and as such wouldn't be yielded to the `foreach`.

Comment: Q: "How to iterate through a HashSet while adding and removing items?"
Person asking question does not realize the difference between List and HashSet so he thinks that new items are added at the end of HashSet, whereas HashSet has no "end". You facilitate that ignorance by downvoting. Thanks for making things worse.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  You posted a solution that fails to accomplish that.  The code compiles, and it doesn't throw an exception, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: It is matter of FACT that code iterates thru "HashSet" while items are getting added and removed. It is exact answer to the question formulated. Person asking simply has incorrect expectation of behavior of HashSet.

Comment: The question specifically states that it wants said iteration to incorporate the changes made during the loop.  This doesn't do that.  It seems that you read the title and not the body of the question that specifically explains why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Servy, again, it DOES incorporate changes made during the loop. If you do not know how CuncurrentDictionary works just read up on it. The changes are getting incorporated, it just not going to be what John is expecting, since HashSets/Dictionaries have no "end" to add to.

Comment: The changes are incorporated if they happen to end up affecting a bucket that is "after" the bucket that the current item is in, they don't if they're affecting a bucket "before" the current item's bucket.  The requirements are for all changes to be observable.  Sounds like you don't understand how `ConcurrentDictionary`'s iterator works.  You should go read up on it.